# How is it parsed: constructing unnamed temporary with braced init list

Tags: c++, c++11, compound-literals

I recently [yet again encountered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376630/464581) the notation

```
( const int[10] ){ 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 }
```

As I recall it's permitted in both C and C++, but via quite different language mechanisms.

I believed that in C++ the formal view is that it's a construction of an unnamed temporary via an epxlicit type conversion `(T)` *cast-expression* that would reduce to a `static_cast`, that constructs an object via C++11 §5.2.9/4:

> **”** an expression `e` can be explicitly converted to a type `T` using a `static_cast` of the form `static_cast<T>(e)` if the declaration `T t(e);` is well-formed, for some invented temporary variable `t` (8.5)

However, the *cast-expression* syntax is defined by C++11 §5.4/2 as being either *unary-expression* or, recursively, a `(` *type-id* `)` *cast-expression*, where the single base case is reduction to *unary-expression*.

And as far as I can tell a *braced init-list* is not an expression?

An alternative view could be that it’s an explicit type conversion via functional notation, C++11 §5.2.3/3,

> **”** a *simple-type-specifier* or *typename-specifier* followed by a *braced-init-list* creates a temporary
>   object of the specified type

but as far as I can tell a *simple-type-specifier* can’t involve parentheses, and a *typename-specifier* involves the keyword `typename`?

Comment: This is not legal C++. The following is the correct way: `Alias<T[N]>{...}`.

Comment: @Xeo What is `Alias` supposed to do?

Comment: `template<class T> using Alias = T;`, a simply using-alias to make the code parseable.

Comment: I think it's conventional to use the name `identity` for that.

Comment: @Xeo: thanks, apparently you're right (about it not being valid). The C++ code failed to compile with Visual C++ 12.0 and with g++ 4.8.2 when `-pedantic` was specified. Without `-pedantic` g++ accepted the code, presumably as a C99 compound literal used as a C++ extension.

Comment: @Xeo: if you write up your comment as answer with proper mention of *simple-template-id* (C++11 §14.2) I'll accept it, then this question will have an SO answer. :)

Comment: @BenVoigt: I don't know, but I've always used `Type`, to my mind self-descriptive. For earlier versions of Visual C++ I used `Type_T_`, which was `template< class Type_ > struct Type_T_{ typedef Type_ T; };`, with ditto more verbose usage.

Answer (score 6):

Per C99 (well, actually N1256 which is the prior draft) 6.5.2.5/4:

> A postfix expression that consists of a parenthesized type name followed by a brace-enclosed list of initializers is a *compound literal*. It provides an unnamed object whose value is given by the initializer list.

Some compilers - [at least g++ and clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/11896810ad4cf5cb) - provide C99 compound literals in C++ as an extension. Semantically, the expression

```
( const int[10] ){ 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 }
```

is a literal of type `const int[10]`: `decltype((const int[10]){ 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 })` is in fact `const int[10]`. **Note well:** There's some disagreement among g++ versions about the exact type: g++ versions before 4.9 says that `decltype((const int[10]){ 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 })` is `const int(&)[10]`. [See this demonstration program](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8acf9f5f4e71d3ad).

You can achieve the same result in standard C++ with explicit type conversion via functional notation, but you must define a type alias for the array type since functional notation requires a *simple-type-specifier*:

```
using foo = const int[10];
foo{ 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
```

or [Xeo's general alias template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24385410/how-is-it-parsed-constructing-unnamed-temporary-with-braced-init-list/24390563#comment37715934_24385410):

```
template <typename T>
using foo = T;
foo<const int[10]>{ 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
```

Comment: Why rvalue? It's not a temporary and can take its address in C just fine. In fact, p5 of the same paragraph says `In either case, the result is an lvalue.`

Comment: @Cubbi You are of course correct, I was expecting `decltype((const int[10]){ 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 })` to be `const int(&)[10]` to indicate an lvalue, when in fact it is simply `const int[10]` just like a literal of any other type.