# what grammars that (int*){} consists of

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

```cpp
int main(){
 auto ptr = (int*){};
}
```

Consider `(int*){}`, what grammars form this? I only find the grammar in `Explicit type conversion` that is possible to denote `(int*){}`, that is:

[expr.cast#2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.cast#2)

> cast-expression:
>
> > - unary-expression
> > - ( type-id ) cast-expression

`int*` is a type-id, hence `(int*)` is the form of `( type-id )`, however I can't find any `unary-expression` in expression grammar tree that can denote `{}`, So, I wonder how to analyze `(int*){}`, what grammars that can form `(int*){}`?

Comment: Use `-pedantic-errors`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin no, it is a non-standard code which uses C99 compound literals extension of gcc/clang

Comment: Oh, so it is basically an empty compound-literal?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin https://godbolt.org/z/ffPvrb

Comment: @LanguageLawyer You mean this code is not a compatible code subject to the c++ standard? Hence I can't find a grammar that denote `{}`.

Comment: Yes, it is not C++, it is [C](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.5p3)

Comment: @LanguageLawyer - yes thanks. I use them all the time in C, The use in ISO C++ had me a bit stumped. Somewhat like the VLA extension gcc provides in g++.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Oh, that will make sense, I'm being curious why I can't find a grammar in the standard, originally it's not c++ code. Thanks.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer In addition, how to show `ast tree` in godblot?

Comment: Under compiler options, see "Add new..." button

Comment: Dup of [How is it parsed: constructing unnamed temporary with braced init list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24385410/how-is-it-parsed-constructing-unnamed-temporary-with-braced-init-list) (there is no accepted answer there, though)

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Your comment has precisely answered my question!

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62768992/11796722) is in bounty. I hope you answers that question.

Comment: I don't know templates well

Comment: What is the meaning of your title? and your question 'what grammars form this'? If your question is about C++, there is only one grammar. Do you mean *productions?*

Comment: @MarquisofLorne I mean which grammars in c++ standard can form `(int*){}` expression.